# Room Database update issue

Tags: java, android

Update multiple fields of an entity in android Room.

I am using android room persistence library for my new project. I want to update multiple fields of the table. I have tried like in my Dao -

```
@Query(" UPDATE " + TABLE_ACC_NO_DEBIT_CARD_LINK + " SET id = :id , device_id = :device_id 
,transaction_key = :transaction_key , mobile = :mobile , email = :email 
,account_no = :account_no , debit_card = :debit_card , bank = :bank 
,is_uploaded = :is_uploaded WHERE device_id = :device_id AND account_no=:account_no")

int updateAccNoDebitCardLink( String device_idc, String account_noc
,String id,String device_id ,String transaction_key
,String mobile,String email,String account_no,String debit_card, String bank
,String is_uploaded);
```

for example

```
@Query(UPDATE TABLENAME <place_holder>)
int updateObject(ObjetEntity objectEntity,String field);
```

What should I pass in place of  , such that the new objectEntity is replaced by old one where the field value matches

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Why are you unsure about the table name?

Comment: is there any option in  custom update query  
//Custom Update
@Query(UPDATE TABLENAME ????)
int updateObject(ObjetEntity objectEntity,String field); instead of  set one by one row name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
@Update
void updateData(MyTable myTable);
```

and put all data into myTable class object and pass it into updateData method..

```
    @Query("update Comment set fname=:fname where id=:id")
void update data(String fname,int id);
```

Comment: actually i want to update entire row  with where condition. set one by  one name isn't  feasible way  so is there any option ??

Answer (score 0):

Try updating values of your table this way. Below is the example in kotlin language.

```
   @Query("UPDATE Test SET test_name=:arg1,test_startDate=:arg2,test_endDate=:arg3,test_location=:arg4 WHERE testId = :arg0")
   fun updateTest( testId: Int,testName:String,testStartTime:String,testEndTime:String,testLocation:String)
```

Here testId, test_name,test_startDate,test_endDate,test_location are the fields of table named Test.